# Setting accessibility identifier on a xib file

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5, ios-ui-automation

I have a xib file which has a view. Under a view, I have few labels... I am working on UIAutomation and hence want to add accessibility identifiers to the view and each of these labels. How can I do it inside the xib? I googled and found that a field named "identifier" should be used... but I cannot see any suck field for view and label.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here:

[image]

You have to set it up manually, so add a key pressing the + button, change the type to String and the name to "identifier".

Comment: On my Xcode it says "Restoration ID" (instead of identifier) under Identity ... Any idea whether its same or not?? I am using XCode 4.5.2.

Comment: I confused this with Cocoa, there isn't an "identifier" field, you have to set it up manually, I changed the picture and edited the post.

Answer (score 2):

in the "Identity Inspector" (3rd tab)

You Will see a header "User Defined Runtime attributes"
there you need to add the key "accessibilityIdentifier" of type string and the value is your id :)